# Avoid spamming to my API that build with Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am building some internal API for my apps/website with Firebase Functions. Internal API as in to let my apps/website to process something on server side, its doesn't mean to open to public use.

My Apps is built with ionic and website is built with angular.

I noticed the one of Firebase Functions Pricing calculation include "Invocations". Is that Invocations means every time when I call the API equal to 1 Invocation? If yes, then the API might be abused by end user, since they able to view the website source and found the API.

I been searching solution in google, some of them suggest to enable authentication and cors, to avoid abuse of the usage. But authentication and cors still counting the Invocations right?

My code structure:

1. client call API by get/post method, pass user TOKEN that get from Firebase Authentication
2. request reach the Firebase Functions
3. server will check the preflight info by using CORS, as well as validate the TOKEN.
4. Return error if didn't pass on the (3), else proceed to execute the function.

So I assume if end user inspect my web source code and get the API URL, they can simply spam my API right? Then my bill will burst because of the load of Invocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect that your project is being abused, which is always possible, [contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to work towards a resolution.

Comment: I see.. But my understanding is correct right? 1 API call = 1 invocation.